# C# Convert string to int (with rounding)

Tags: c#, .net

What's the easiest way to get a string with the value of "76.10" into an int rounded to 76?

I've tried a few different ways using Convert.ToInt32 and Decimal but I can't seem to get it right?

Edit: Here's the code Jon helped me with:

```
            decimal t = Math.Round(decimal.Parse(info.HDDStatus));
            int v = (int)t;
```

Comment: i'm sure this is a dupe - Math.Round is your answer OP

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use `Decimal.Parse` to parse it, and then [`Math.Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa340225.aspx) (or potentially [`Math.Floor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7ycc7xh.aspx) depending on how you want numbers like "76.7" to be handled) to round it. *Then* convert to an integer just by casting.

I would suggest using `decimal` rather than `double` as you're inherently talking about a *decimal* number (as that's how it's represented in text).

The exact method of parsing will depend on culture - would you expect text of "76,10" to appear in a European context, or will it always use "." as the decimal point, for example?

Comment: Thanks for explaining it, I've added the code I'm using from this into the original question, it works, but Is it the best way?

Comment: @JoeBeez: Depending on exactly how you want the value to be rounded, and exactly how you want it to be parsed, yes. Think about different cultures, and values liker "76.6" and "76.5".

Answer (score 3):

1. Convert it to double first and use Math.Floor()
2. Extract the substring (76) first .

```
string s = "76.7"; 
int n = int.Parse(s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf('.')));
```